# ScriptedPatchRequest documentation

Tags: ravendb

Is there any documentation about ScriptedPatchRequest on ravendb? 
I could only find something here: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/faq/denormalized-updates

I want to use this nice feature but don't know about the other methods like "LoadDocument" that are available through javascript patch.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs here: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/partial-document-updates

And here is a bunch more text that SO requires me to put in.